# How to specify useBean tag for array in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl

I am trying to pass an arraylist in a bean to be processed by a JSTL foreach in a JSP.
I don't know how to specify the useBean tag for the collection because tomcat kicks back a stack trace exception 
**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.business.PersonBeanModel**

The servlet sends the arraylist like so:

```
List<PersonBeanModel> people = ManageEmployee.getpeople();
request.setAttribute("jsppeople", people);
```

The JSP contains:

```
<jsp:useBean id="jsppeople" scope="request" class="com.business.PersonBeanModel" />

    <c:forEach items="${jsppeople}" var="myperson">
       ${myperson.name}
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Remove the `<jsp:useBean>`...

Comment: Remove the <useBean> line from your JSP and try again. You put jsppeople into scope in your Servlet.

Comment: Well that was simple....thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `jsppeople` attribute is a `List`, not a `PersonBeanModel`, which is what you're trying to do in the `<jsp:bean>`:

```
<jsp:useBean id="jsppeople" scope="request" class="com.business.PersonBeanModel" />
```

So, the solution would be to remove this line and just keep using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) and [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).